# Using jQuery onmousedown and onmouseup on a JSF panelgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2

I'm using both jQuery and JSF elements on a page.

My requirement is that a panelGrid element redirects the user when clicked.
I've achieved this by doing the following:

```
    <h:panelGrid>
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.click"/>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <div>
            <h:panelGroup>
                <img src="../resources/img/icon_circle_footer.png" width="20px" height="20px" />
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div><b>R800,00</b></div>
                        <div>per passenger</div>
                    </div>
                    <div>Company Name</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>Timespan</div>
                        <div>non-stop</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="../resources/img/icon_circle_footer.png" width="20px" height="20px" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </div>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGrid>
```

This works just fine, but currently there is nothing to indicate to the user that the element has been clicked.

I want to change the background of the element when the user clicks on it, and have tried the following:

```
<h:panelGrid onmousedown="mousedown(this);" onmouseup="mouseup(this);">
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.clickGrid}"
</h:panelGrid>

<script>
    function mousedown(element) {
        element.toggleClass("hilite");
    }

    function mouseup(element) {
        element.toggleClass("hilite");
    }
</script>
```

When clicking the element, the JS breaks and logs this to the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableElement> as no method 'toggleClass'`. I understand the problem, but I've searched for a similar method that I can apply to table elements, with no luck.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes DOM objects do not have a toggleClass method, its a jQuery method that you are trying to call on them.

if you have jQuery included then this would be the solution:

`$(element).toggleClass("hilite");`

Comment: I assume you mean `$(element).onclick(function() { $(element).toggleClass("hilite"); }` ?

Comment: no! this way: function mousedown(element) {
        $(element).toggleClass("hilite");
    } and the same thing for mouseup function

Comment: Indeed, just replace `element` in your code by `$(element)`. The `$(element)` converts a HTML DOM element to a jQuery object on which you can then invoke all jQuery specific functions. Note that this all has got nothing to do with JSF.